# Is there a way to filter with the new YouTrack REST API?

Tags: youtrack, youtrack-api

I have been tasked to build a custom interface for Youtrack and am using the new YouTrack APIs - docs here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/youtrack-rest-api-reference.html. I am querying for a full list of issues which returns 1.17 MB of data. The problem is this takes a while and I only need issues with specific fields ie `Priority=1` and `Type=Task`.

**Is there a way to filter with the new APIs so I don't return 1.17 MB of data?**

I see that the deprecated APIs (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/deprecated-rest-api-reference.html) have a `filter` field, but I cannot find one in the new API documentation. I have tried including `filter=Priority` and `filter=Priority(name=1)` to see if there are some undocumented filtering methods, but no luck thus far.

Example call: `GET https://example.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/api/issues?fields=id,description,fields(id,name,value(id,name))` which returns 1.17 MB of data.

Ideally, I would like to do `GET https://example.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/api/issues?filter=Priority(name=1),fields=...` or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to apply a filter to the returned issues list the same way as for the old API. Have a look at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/resource-api-issues.html#get_all-Issue-method. The only difference in this regard is that the field field is called 'query', not 'filter'.